# Is there any faster way to iterate through rows from Sqlite query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am using the following lines for looping on rows of a Sqlite query.

```
this.open(); // opening db
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strQuery, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
do {    

    // do something    

} while (cursor.moveToNext());

cursor.close();
```

When the number of rows is about 15000 it takes long time. **It takes about 4 seconds for empty `while` block** and about 6 second for `while` block that has some codes. It shows that iterating on rows in this way is time consuming.

Is there any faster way for looping on rows in android and Sqlite?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure of your use cases for SQLite, but this may be of use: http://shopwith.it/2011/12/16/how-to-improve-android-app-performance-by-caching-data-in-sqlite-and-images-to-the-sd-card-android-developer-tips/

Comment: If you're up for it, can you explain why you need to retrieve so many records at once? Also can't you collapse to less in your SELECT statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optimizing what you do inside the loop is the only way of improving the speed of the whole operation. For instance if you're doing `getColumnIndex` calls on every iteration, you will be loosing precious time. Do it once, store the value.

Use `traceView` to locate where you're loosing time and improve it there. Sadly I can't give a concrete answer, since I don't know what you're doing inside the loop.

---

[Traceview Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)